# Transaction management in Parse.com

Tags: transactions, parse-platform

Does parse.com support transactions ?
I am trying to insert new rows into two different tables.
If an error occurs during an insert into one of the table then the whole transaction 
needs to be rolled back.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't.

You could handle the situation in Cloud Code and if one of save operations fail then perform delete of already saved object.

For cloud code doc see: https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions